# Google Cloud Vision - PHP - "Request had insufficient authentication scopes"

Tags: php, google-cloud-vision

Trying to use Google Cloud vision to analyze files already stored in Google Cloud Storage. My code:

```
$vision = new VisionClient([
                            'projectId'   => $projectId,
                            'keyFilePath' => <json key file>,
                            'scopes'      => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
                           ]);
```

I grab a full http path to my file, which is valid, but when I:

```
$image = $vision->image( fopen(<file>, 'r'),  [ 'LABEL_DETECTION' ]);
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 
 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message '{
    "error": {
         "code": 403,
         "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
         "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
  }'
```

I can open the file fine ($x = fopen(filename) works), so I'm not sure what's happening here. Is there a way I can check what my service client has in the way of permissions?

Comment: check the API docs for what scopes you need in order to perform that action.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - I hadn't properly gone through all authorization steps.